# Page for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I'm a newbie in WordPress and I've just created a new custom-post type called arts. Is there a way I can create a custom page to display the 'art's custom type? The custom-post type has thumbnails which I'll be displaying on the post and 'arts'are a bit more different form other posts. Any help offered will be highly regarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I f you set the argument `has_archive` in [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) to `TRUE` you get an archive automatically.

Depending on your slug it will be available on `/arts/` probably.

To customize the look of that page use a [template `archive-{post_type}.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display).

Comment: I want to customize how the page will look because it has links to images in the post meta.

Comment: I made an update to my answer.